# SetCap with NFS

Tags: mpi, hpc, nfs, raw-sockets, linux-capabilities

I am working on a project that requires using raw_sockets and raw sockets to work needs CAP_NET_RAW we used setcap and it worked fine, now the executable is on NFS, and nw setcap can’t be used is their a work around? Thanks in advance

I tried chown root and chmod u+s to increase prevelage of my executable but it didn’t work

Comment: What options is this NFS mount mounted with? In other words, if you run `mount`, what options are listed in the line representing the NFS mount?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Extended File Attributes on NFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24629459/how-to-use-extended-file-attributes-on-nfs)

Answer (score 1):

Your app uses raw sockets, and raw sockets requires that the process have `CAP_NET_RAW` capability, correct?

> https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man7/packet.7.html,
>
> In  order to create a packet socket, a process must have the
> CAP_NET_RAW capability in the user namespace that governs its network
> namespace.

You've been relying on [extended attributes](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html) to associate CAP_NET_RAW capability with your app's executable file, but your NFS server doesn't support this, correct?

Here's a potential workaround:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/44103544/421195
>
> You can use [fuse_xattrs](https://github.com/fbarriga/fuse_xattrs) (a
> fuse filesystem layer) to emulate extended attributes (xattrs) on NFS
> shares. Basically you have to do:
>
> 1. mount the NFS share. e.g.: /mnt/shared_data
> 2. mount the fuse xattr layer:
>
>    ```
>    $ fuse_xattrs /mnt/shared_data /mnt/shared_data_with_xattrs
>    ```
>
> Now all the files on `/mnt/shared_data` can be accessed on
> `/mnt/shared_data_with_xattrs` with xattrs support. The extended
> attributes will be stored on sidecar files. The extended attributes
> are not going to be stored on the server filesystem as extended
> attributes, they are going to be stored in sidecar files.
>
> Sadly this is only a work-around.
>
> disclaimer: I'm the author of fuse_xattrs.
>
> [fbarriga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4941600/fbarriga)

Comment: Do you need to run `fuse_xattrs` as root? Should there be a `sudo` in there somewhere?